# How to change properties for just one copy of the prefab?

Tags: unity, c#

I have created Dino object, which is the enemy in the game and it needs to be on the several positions in the game (3 or 4). So I have created a script for it and I want something like that:
When player is close to it, it should change it's speed, direction maybe, and the animation.
I have a script which is attached to the Dino Object. After I make the copies of the Dino object in the project.
The problem is, when player is close to the first Dino the changes are made on all the Dinos in the Scene. So how can I fix that? Here is my Dino Script:

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class Dino : MonoBehaviour
{
    private float speed = 1f;
    private Vector2 tempPos;
    private SpriteRenderer sr;
    private float playerPos;
    private float dinoPos;
    private Animator animator;

    void Awake()
    {
        sr = GetComponent<SpriteRenderer>();
        animator = GetComponent<Animator>();
    }

    // Start is called before the first frame update
    void Start()
    {
        
    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update()
    {
        DinoMovement();
    }

    private void OnCollisionEnter2D(Collision2D collision)
    {
        if (collision.gameObject.CompareTag("Wall"))
        {
            sr.flipX = !sr.flipX;
            speed = -speed;
        }
    }

    void DinoMovement()
    {
        playerPos = GameObject.Find("Player").transform.position.x;
        //wallPos = GameObject.FindGameObjectWithTag("Wall").transform.position.x;
        dinoPos = transform.position.x;

        //move Dino
        tempPos = transform.position;
        tempPos.x += speed * Time.deltaTime;
        transform.position = tempPos;


        //Dino Follows Player
        int pictw = WallDestroy.PlayerIsCloseToWall;

        if (pictw == 1)
        {
            if (playerPos < dinoPos - 2)
            {
                speed = -2f;
                sr.flipX = true;
                animator.SetBool("DinoRunParam", true);
            }
            else if (playerPos > dinoPos + 2)
            {
                speed = 2f;
                sr.flipX = false;
                animator.SetBool("DinoRunParam", true);
            }
        }
    }

}
```

Here is the transparent wall script, which controls if the Player is close to that wall, when Dino should change some properties.

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class WallDestroy : MonoBehaviour
{
    private float tempPos;
    private float playerPos;
    private static int playerIsCloseToWall = 0;
    // Start is called before the first frame update
    void Start()
    {
        
    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update()
    {
        tempPos = transform.position.x;
        playerPos = GameObject.Find("Player").transform.position.x;

        if(tempPos - playerPos < 7)
        {
            playerIsCloseToWall = 1;
            Destroy(this.gameObject);
        }
    }

    public static int PlayerIsCloseToWall
    {
        get { return playerIsCloseToWall; }
        set { playerIsCloseToWall = value; }

    }
}
```

Here is the Player Script if needed:

````
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class MaleZombie : MonoBehaviour
{
    [SerializeField]
    private float speed = 3f;
    private float jumpForce = 6f;
    private bool isGrounded = true;
    private Vector2 tempPos;
    private SpriteRenderer sr;
    private Animator animator;
    private Rigidbody2D rb;

    // Awake
    void Awake()
    {
        sr = GetComponent<SpriteRenderer>();
        animator = GetComponent<Animator>();
        rb = GetComponent<Rigidbody2D>();
    }

    // Start is called before the first frame update
    void Start()
    {
        
    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update()
    {
        ZombieMove();
        ZombieJump();
        ZombieAttack();
    }

    // This function is called once per 0.02 sec.
    void FixedUpdate()
    {
        
    }

    void ZombieMove()
    {
        tempPos = transform.position;
        float h = Input.GetAxisRaw("Horizontal");

        if (h > 0)
        {
            tempPos.x += speed * Time.deltaTime;
            sr.flipX = false;
            animator.SetBool("WalkParam", true);
        }
        else if (h < 0)
        {
            tempPos.x -= speed * Time.deltaTime;
            sr.flipX = true;
            animator.SetBool("WalkParam", true);
        }
        else
        {
            animator.SetBool("WalkParam", false);
        }
        transform.position = tempPos;

    }

    void ZombieJump()
    {
        if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.UpArrow) && isGrounded == true)
        {
            rb.AddForce(new Vector2(0f, jumpForce), ForceMode2D.Impulse);
            isGrounded = false;
        }
    }

    private void OnCollisionEnter2D(Collision2D collision)
    {
        if (collision.gameObject.CompareTag("Ground"))
        {
            isGrounded = true;
        }
    }

    void ZombieAttack()
    {
        if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.Space))
     // if (Input.GetButtonDown("Jump"))
        {
            animator.Play("Attack");
        }
    }

}

```
````

Comment: From the code you've shown, it's not obvious why this would affect all dinos in sync. I'd assume each dino has a copy of this script attached, which should be referring to its own transform. You aren't using a static variable for `speed`, are you? Try expanding the sample you've shown, aiming for a Minimal Complete Verifiable Example: a reader should be able to copy this into a new, empty project, compile, and reproduce the problem you're seeing. Once we can reproduce the problem, we can test potential fixes to be sure they'll work for you.

Comment: Thank you for your response. I am a beginner in Unity and C# and on this website as well, so I don't know how to use it properly. I have edited my question.

Comment: Your PlayerIsCloseToWall script looks suspect. It's using a static variable to track whether the player has ever gotten close to any wall, and never resetting it. Does your dino problem still occur if you temporarily remove the wall stuff from the equation? (This is part of making a "Minimal" Complete Verifiable Example: cutting away anything that might confuse the issue to narrow down the set of possible causes). You can make a copy of your project and delete stuff from it, then check if the problem still occurs.